# Can't access embedded struct when I pass an instance of my outer structinto a slice of an interface, which the outer struct implements

Tags: go, struct, interface, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type shape struct {
    name string
}

type square struct {
    shape
    length int
}

type twoDimensional interface {
    area() int
}

func (s square) area() int {
    return s.length * s.length
}


func main() {
    s1 := square{
        length: 2,
    }
    s1.name = "spongebob"
    
    
    allSquares := []twoDimensional{
        s1,
    }
    
    fmt.Println(allSquares[0].name)
}
```

This is giving me the following error:
`./prog.go:36:27: allSquares[0].name undefined (type twoDimensional has no field or method name)`

I'm confused about what's going on here. Type square is embedded with type shape, and type square also implements the twoDimensional interface.

If I pass an instance of square into a slice of twoDimensionals, how come I can no longer access type shape from my square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface itself does not have `.name` attribute. You need to use type assertion `allSquares[0].(square)` as the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type shape struct {
    name string
}

type square struct {
    shape
    length int
}

type twoDimensional interface {
    area() int
}

func (s square) area() int {
    return s.length * s.length
}

func main() {
    s1 := square{
        length: 2,
    }
    s1.name = "spongebob"

    allSquares := []twoDimensional{
        s1,
    }

    fmt.Println(allSquares[0].(square).name)
}
```